# Reading incoming sms

Tags: android, sms

I have been using this tutorial for reading incomging message. But Im not able to see Toast message. Dont know why ?
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

I even downloaded the app and tried in my HTC Desire having Android 2.2

Is the code given in tutorial fine or wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine in that article. Are you seeing any relevant messages or errors in the logs? Why not add some logging statements to the code and see what is being executed?

Comment: Problem is that I can run 2 instance of the emulator, But cant open app in both the emulator.

Comment: Still trying some how I got the broadcast receiver is not getting called.

Comment: If you have some other way to do this. Please you can suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is for Android 1.5. Are you even compiling against 1.5 (API Level 3)?

Comment: No. Im compiling against 2.2 .. Can u tell me what i can do to put this in work ?

Comment: You'll have to compile against 1.5, or better yet, find a more recent tutorial. This tutorial is really old. And there were major changes between version 1.5 and 1.6.